# Find extension of file from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-extension

I want to find what is the extension of file in current URL.
I have used
`http://tol.imagingtech.com/eIL/cgi-bin/eIL.pl?ACTION=get_trans_doc&DOC=ALL&CAB_NAME=TOL_AP_2012&WHSE=18&PAYEE=23003655&INV=01235770`

The extension of this file is (.pdf) how can i get this. Sometimes it will be (.doc,.txt,.jpeg) so i want the exact one.

Following is the code which i used to retrieve file extension

`var extFile = Document.DocumentFilePath.Split('.');

  return "Backup document." + extFile[extFile.Length-1].Trim().ToLower();`

It works fine for normal local path but it fails to retrieve extension which DocumentFilePath is url.

Comment: What do you mean by "file in current URL", how do you request that URL?

Answer (score 6):

I think that there is no way to get the file type without actually getting it.

You can get the information in the response `header` once your request is completed.

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

You can do it in C# using `WebClient`

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 var url = "http://tol.imagingtech.com/eIL/cgi-bin/eIL.pl?ACTION=get_trans_doc&DOC=ALL&CAB_NAME=TOL_AP_2012&WHSE=18&PAYEE=23003655&INV=01235770";
 string data = client.DownloadString(url);
 string contentType = client.Headers["Content-Type"];
```

Comment: I was not able to get your answer...can you please post c# code to retrieve file extension.

Comment: I had posted the code in my question "Document.DocumentFilePath " contain that path. from which i want to retrieve extension.

Comment: In web you can get guess the file type by just look at URL. For example a url like "http://www.expample.com/123232" can be a webpage, an image, or any other file depending upon the server.

Comment: "DownloadString" method showing error "System.Net.WebClient does not contain definition for DownloadString() " I also added System.Net namespace.

Comment: try "client.DownloadData" instead.

Comment: Both methods are available in in the web client, which .net version you are using?

Comment: These two methods are even available in .Net 2.0. you can look at the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I think there is another class in project named WebClinet. Please check it.

Comment: use ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"]

Answer (score 3):

Do a HEAD request to the URL and take a look at the `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME` header if that's being used.

Comment: @Chets no. Not until you post the code that you use to retreive the file from the URL. Put that in your question. For example `http://foo/bar/` can serve a file called `baz.jpg`, and even `http://foo/bar.gif` can actually serve `qux.exe`. Any URL can serve any file extension, so you'll have to do a request to the URL to get the real file.

Answer (score 1):

To find the content type, take it from the Http response as follows:

```
byte[] myDataBuffer = webClient.DownloadData(fileAbsoluteUrl);
string contentType = webClient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"];
```